# eclipse cdt - how to set a break point by name?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I use the 'b __cxa__throw' in the gdb term to set a breakpoint on general throw. This is a nice trick to debug.

How can i set a similar bp in eclipse cdt? i.e i wish to set a bp based on method/func name.

Note that for such a debug a minimal debug info is required, i.e. just method/func names, nothing else.

10x
Rabin

Answer (score 0):

To place a breakpoint in CDT:

1. Locate the CDT breakpoints window (e.g. by Window -> Show View -> Breakpoints), open the dropdown menu, pick "Add Function Breakpoint"
2. Fill in the "Function name" field with a function name or any [GDB location specification](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html) (e.g. `*0x4017e0`, *filename:linenum* )
3. Press "OK"

[image]

To break on C++ `throw`, you could use "Add Event Breakpoint" then set the Event Type to "exception thrown". Just like using `catch throw` in the GDB CLI.